# insert and update a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to update all the collection field profile.email with emails.[0].address just something like this in SQL:

```
 update dbo.users
  set profile.email=emials.[0].address
```

I know this stupid code won't work on SQL either. Just put it to make it sensible for what I need.

it is something like this,but is not working:

```
  db.getCollection('users').update(
   {_id: "QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws"},
    {$set:
        {'profile.email': db.getCollection('users').aggregate({$match: {_id:'QYoHQkTuTXnEC6Pws'}}, 
             {$project: {_id:0,email: {$arrayElemAt: 
 ['$emails.address',0]}}})
      }
  }
 )
```

the result is not true :

```
  "email" : {
        "_batch" : [ 
            {
                "email" : "deleted_sadaf@ham.com"
            }
        ],
        "_useReadCommands" : true,
        "_cursorid" : NumberLong(0),
        "_batchSize" : undefined,
        "_ns" : "meteor.users",
        "_db" : {
            "_mongo" : {
                "slaveOk" : true,
                "host" : "localhost:3001",
                "defaultDB" : "",
                "_readMode" : "commands",
                "_writeMode" : "commands"
            },
            "_name" : "meteor"
        },
        "_collName" : "users",
        "_cursorHandle" : {}
    }
```

Comment: What is your mongo version?

Comment: mongo version is 3.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over each document and update to achieve expected result.

```
db.users.find({}).forEach(function (user) {
   db.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$set: {'profile.email': user.emails[0].address}});
});
```

Comment: I run code in robomongo and get this error  TypeError: db.getCollection(...).snapshot is not a function :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: should I execute from Js file?

Comment: I don't know how to appreciate your help. it does work! thank you so much

Comment: Just instead of db.users:  
db.getCollection('users')

Comment: :but there is a problem i have 300 document but when i run code just 20 of it get updated why?

Answer (score -1):

```
db.users.update({_id: "doc id"},
    {$set: {'profile.email': db.users.find({_id: "doc id"}).emails[0].address}
})
```

Your task has 2 steps:
1. get the email address, which is performed by "db.users.find"
2. update the document, which is performed by "db.users.update"

Comment: I want to apply it for whole of the collection not just specific Id. Does it work like this just by removing _id part?

Comment: you can use the forEach function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/